# Slim 3 hosted on VPS can't find templates directory

Tags: .htaccess, location, hosting, slim, vps

today I configured my slim app on my web server (VPS). 
I structured the project so that my public_html contains the Slim's index file and .htaccess file, and the background files are in the folder before (/../public_html) (I imagined that's the right configuration since the "public" files of the app are in the "public" folder.
Sadly I was wrong, if I browser to my website I get a slim error saying the template :

```
The "templates" directory does not exist ("/var/www/mywebsitefolder/public_html/templates").
```

Which is weird cause I said my isettings.php file to locate the templates folder inside the one BEFORE public_html, as stated in my file :

```
// Renderer settings
    'renderer' => [
        'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/',
    ],
```

So it should look inside /../templates, but it's not happening, also that's how I configured my .htaccess inside public_html where index.php is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And my folders structure (maybe it can help)

```
- **my website apache folder**
 - Controllers
 - Models
 - src
 - templates
 - vendor
 - public_html
   - css
   - imgs
   - js
   - index.php 
   - .htaccess
```

Any suggestions? I followed the right logic?

Comment: I also ran into this recently.  What templating engine are you using?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Slim, so I apologize if this answer is naive or is doing things the wrong way.

I had the same problem - the application I created worked locally (using `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php`).  When I moved it to a VPS, it stopped working because it was looking for the template directory within the `public` directory.

I fixed it by initializing Twig like this (in `src/dependencies.php`):

```
// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {

    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig(
        $container->get('settings')['renderer']['template_path']
    );

    // Removed more Twig setup code

    return $view;
};
```

Originally Twig was being initialized with the string `"templates"` rather than a call to the `template_path` setting.

Comment: Amazing! Totally didn't think about that, thanks, I guess I'll mark this as correct, I actually solved this by moving templates directory to public, and everything works, but your method is "cleaner".